# Python: Attribute Error _Screen has no attribute _mode

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

So I am doing an object-oriented program using turtle, a python library that comes with python already. The way that I have been asked to do it includes inheritance. I have included my files and my error in the pastebin links below.

[The error I am getting](http://pastebin.com/6rLQLymh), and my files:

- [RaceProgramModule](http://pastebin.com/2W8fTVje)
- [TurtleRacerModule](http://pastebin.com/1pykz29A)
- [RaceTrackModule](http://pastebin.com/YsNdPTdB)

So far as I can tell, which is easily found in the error, is that when I try to initialize the 
`Turtle` class in the `TurtleRacer` class, it says that it doesn't have an attribute called `_mode`.
This is leading me to believe that the screen I am creating is not reaching the Turtles that I am creating. However, I do not know how to solve this issue practically without just throwing everything together in one file. The `RaceProgram` class must create any `TurtleRacer` objects and the `RaceTrack` object. So I am unsure of how to link the two. I've tried passing the `_racetrack` object to the `TurtleRacer` class for the `__init__` method, but it didn't change anything. Does anyone have any suggestions of what I can do?

Edit:
Here are the specific sections of code that I am interested in, I apologize for not bringing this to notice outright.

[This](http://pastebin.com/QRnWBfpd) is the part of the main class where I create the turtles.

[This](http://pastebin.com/bVjL91U6) is the `__init__` of the `TurtleRacer` class. The specific line of code that is failing is line number 6.

Comment: I tried to edit the question to insert the pastebin links into, but is way too much code. You should try to narrow it down and show the exception (that's good), but then only particular interconnected areas of the code, discarding the rest.

Comment: I have updated the question slightly. I added the specific line of notice, which is a part of the second link I added.

Comment: Thank you Ourous for suggesting those edits, much appreciated.